# Is SpecFlow dead?

Tags: .net, visual-studio, specflow

It seems that SpecFlow is dead. http://www.specflow.org isn't being updated much more than for advertising, and the last official addin for Visual Studio is for 2012.

Is SpecFlow dead, and if so, what's the next great thing to take its place, particularly for .Net and Visual Studio?

Comment: Apparently, version 2 is in the works: http://us5.campaign-archive2.com/?u=de77de3e06165e04f743d0e6c&id=1cedde9daf

Comment: For whoever downvoted, can you please explain why? I would like to start with BDD, but if I can't ask a question here anymore without having to please 47 moderators on asking the question perfectly, then I'm at a dead end, and this site is a whole lot less useful than it used to be.

Comment: I didn't downvote, but I did vote to close because the [help/on-topic] clearly says *Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam.*, and asking about the "next great thing" clearly fits into that category.

Comment: It used to be that people with 2000000000 reputation would attempt to help make the question useful. Now everyone wants to close the question. I'm not looking to generate spam. I'm looking to start a new, large project with BDD or something like it, and I would like to choose a tool that isn't going to be gone tomorrow. If this site isn't the place to go to answer a question, then where is?

Comment: @GaTechThomas [this might be a better fit](http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/), although I think that with a bit of tweaking (like 'are people using Specflow on large projects still? Have you had issues with it?' rather then 'whats the next great thing') the question is still a valid one

Comment: Just look at the company's life-signs.  Their last twitter post was January 27th, it announces the training schedule for 2015.  It is like me not having bought a new pair of glasses for the past 5 years, the old ones work just fine.  We are not dead, we are *mature*.

Comment: @GaTechThomas it is your responsibility as question-asker to make the question useful. It's also your responsibility to find an appropriate place to ask it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I do not think that SpecFlow is dead at all. In fact Specflow is the best tool I've seen in the space, especially for .NET.

There have been several pull requests in recent months, but you are right that there seems to be a bit of 'maintenance apathy' as there have not been any new versions (even beta versions) made in a good while.

As noted in the comments there is a push started recently for v2, which hopefully will also result in having more regular releases as new functionality is developed.

As ever with something that is open source, be the change to you want to see.